# Maven Surefire: run a single unit test

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin, unit-testing

I know that it's possible to run a specific test class with `-Dtest=MyTest`.  But is it possible to run a specific test *within* that class?

I.e. if `MyTest` defines `testFoo()` and `testBar()`, is there a way to specify that only `testfoo()` should be run?

I'm aware that it's trivially easy to do this in an IDE, but I occasionally need to run tests on the command line on another server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be available as of Surefire 2.8, see [SUREFIRE-577](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-577)

Answer (score 5):

From [Running a Single Test Using Maven Surefire Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html)

> With version 2.7.3, you can run only n tests in a single Test Class.
>
> NOTE : it's supported for junit 4.x and TestNG.
>
> You must use the following syntax
>
> `mvn -Dtest=TestCircle#mytest test`
>
> You can use patterns too
>
> `mvn -Dtest=TestCircle#test* test`

Answer (score 1):

Don't think its available. You can work around it by passing some system properties & ignore execution of tests based on the property value. However it does not seem to add a great value add. There is also TestNG which offers additional features.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html

Answer (score 0):

To execute one Test at a time, run mvn test

```
mvn -Dtest=MyUnitlTest test
```

To execute one Test at a time and a specific method from it:

```
mvn -Dtest=MyUnitTest#method test
```

where MyUnitTest is the name of your test and #method is the name of your method.

Execute tests with surefire:

```
mvn surefire:test
```